# How to reshape data in SPSS

Tags: reshape, spss

I have data from a survey. The question looks like this:

```
Did you do any of the following activities during your PhD

                             Yes, paid by my school. Yes, paid by me.  No. 

Attended an internationl conference?
Bought textbooks?
```

The data is automatically saved in a spreadsheet in this way:

```
id conf.1 conf.2 conf.3 text.1 text.2 text.3

1    1                              1
2           1               1
3                   1       1
4                   1                    1
5
```

This means participant 1 attended a conference paid by her university; particiapnt 2 attended the conference paid by him, and participant 3 didn't go.

I want to merge conf.1, conf.2 and conf.3 and text.1, text.2 and text.3 in single variables

```
id new.conf new.text

1   1        2
2   2        1
3   3        1
4   3        3

where the number now respresents the categories of the survey question

Thanks for your help
```

Comment: I found the answer http://www.arts.unsw.edu.au/gargyrous/extra_chapters/SPSSMultipleResponseCommand.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure given your description multiple response sets (what you [link to](http://www.arts.unsw.edu.au/gargyrous/extra_chapters/SPSSMultipleResponseCommand.pdf) in the comment to your question) is really what you want. In this example, you don't need to reshape your data at all, and a simple `DO REPEAT` command will suffice to make your `new.conf` and `new.text` variables. Example below:

```
data list free /id conf.1 conf.2 conf.3 text.1 text.2 text.3.
begin data
1 1 0 0 0 1 0 
2 0 1 0 1 0 0 
3 0 0 1 1 0 0 
4 0 0 1 0 0 1 
5 0 0 0 0 0 0 
end data.
dataset name conf.
*this is to replicate missing data as specified originally.
recode conf.1 to text.3 (0 = SYSMIS)(ELSE = COPY).

compute new.conf = 0.
compute new.text = 0.
do repeat conf_list = conf.1 to conf.3 /text_list = text.1 to text.3 /#i = 1 to 3.
    if conf_list = 1 new.conf = #i.
    if text_list = 1 new.text = #i.
end repeat.
```

The command `list all` then produces the following output (note how I initialized the variables to 0 values, not really needed but how I usually treat things):

> ```
>   id   conf.1   conf.2   conf.3   text.1   text.2   text.3 new.conf new.text
>
> 1.00     1.00      .        .        .       1.00      .       1.00     2.00
> 2.00      .       1.00      .       1.00      .        .       2.00     1.00
> 3.00      .        .       1.00     1.00      .        .       3.00     1.00
> 4.00      .        .       1.00      .        .       1.00     3.00     3.00
> 5.00      .        .        .        .        .        .        .00      .00
> ```
>
> Number of cases read:  5    Number of cases listed:  5

It is possible you do want to reshape the data, although if both the conf and text list variables are mutually exclusive there is no reason. If do you need to reshape data, see the help for the command `VARSTOCASES` for reshaping from wide to long, and `CASESTOVARS` for reshaping from long to wide.